# How to get Spinner inside ListView work in Android?

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I am developing an app in which I need a ListView whose rows have a TextView, 2 CheckBox and a Spinner.

However, I am experiencing issues with `onItemSelected()` of the Spinner, as it gets called each time it is displayed for each row. In this method I am updating database records with the selected option, but as Android calls it automatically, every time the items get reset because Android calls it with position 0 and this is the value updated in the database.

I have read a lot of links about the issue with `onItemSelected()` and some hacks, but all of them are to use without a ListView. Any points here?

I have tried to track in a List which positions are actually displayed to make it work but it does not. I think it is because of the recycling in Android that causes the troubleshooting method get called for Spinners already shown!

So the point is: **How can I differenciate a real call to `onItemSelected()` because of a user selection from the Android call when displaying the Spinner?**

Here is the code of my adapter that extends SimpleCursorAdapter.

Thank you so much in advance.

```
public ParticipationAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    mActivity = (Activity)context;
    ParticipationComment.ParticipationCommentManager commentManager = new ParticipationComment.ParticipationCommentManager(mActivity);
    mParticipationCommentsCursor = commentManager.get();
    mActivity.startManagingCursor(mParticipationCommentsCursor);
    commentManager.detach();
    mPositionsOfCursorIds = getPositionsOfCursorIds(mParticipationCommentsCursor);
    mSpinnerPositionsDisplayed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int participationPosition, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Cursor participationsCursor = getCursor();
    mActivity.startManagingCursor(participationsCursor);
    participationsCursor.moveToPosition(participationPosition);
    View participationRow;
    if (convertView == null) {
        participationRow = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.participation_row_student, null);
    } else {
        mSpinnerPositionsDisplayed.remove((Integer)convertView.getTag());
        participationRow = convertView;
    }
    participationRow.setTag(participationPosition);
    Spinner commentSpinner = (Spinner)participationRow.findViewById(R.id.participation_comment_id_spinner);
    SimpleCursorAdapter commentSpinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            mActivity,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            mParticipationCommentsCursor,
            new String[] {DatabaseManager.NAME},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
    );
    commentSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    commentSpinner.setAdapter(commentSpinnerAdapter);
    long participationCommentId = participationsCursor.getLong(participationsCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.PARTICIPATION_COMMENT_ID));
    if (participationCommentId != 0) {
        commentSpinner.setSelection(mPositionsOfCursorIds.get(participationCommentId));
    }
    commentSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            participationsCursor.moveToPosition(participationPosition);
            if (!mSpinnerPositionsDisplayed.contains(participationPosition)) {
                // Android calls this method the first time a Spinner is displayed,
                // to differentiate from a real user click we check if the current Spinner's position
                // in the ListView is being shown
                mSpinnerPositionsDisplayed.add(participationPosition);
            } else {
                ParticipationComment participationComment = new ParticipationComment((Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Participation.ParticipationManager participationManager = new Participation.ParticipationManager(mActivity);
                Participation participation = new Participation(participationsCursor);
                participation.setConnectionProfileParticipationCommentId(participationComment.getConnectionProfileId());
                participation.setParticipationCommentId(participationComment.getIdOpenErp());
                participation.setChanged(true);
                participationManager.update(participation);
                participationManager.detach();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Not used
        }
    });
    TextView studentName = (TextView)participationRow.findViewById(R.id.participation_student_name);
    studentName.setText(participationsCursor.getString(participationsCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.NAME)));
    CheckBox expectedPresent = (CheckBox)participationRow.findViewById(R.id.participation_expected_present_value);
    expectedPresent.setChecked(participationsCursor.getInt(participationsCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.EXPECTED_PRESENT)) == 1);
    CheckBox present = (CheckBox)participationRow.findViewById(R.id.participation_present_value);
    present.setChecked(participationsCursor.getInt(participationsCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.PRESENT)) == 1);
    return participationRow;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way is to use a AlertDialog Variant.. like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).. and create a button which initially has the first selection as its Text and its changed based on the AlertDialog choice..

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Tomorrow I will try it and say something to you! But I will use `public AlertDialog.Builder setCursor (Cursor cursor, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener, String labelColumn)` instead, because I have the origin data in a db table. I think that with this approach I will be able to allow the user to select none of the choices, that is what I actually need and is not possible using the Spinner.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I have finally implemented the selection inside the ListView with buttons and alertDialogs as you suggested. This works great! I used the method `setSingleChoiceItems()` in the dialog, as it allows you to define a default selection. I have upvoted and accepted your answer to give you +25 rep! :)

Comment: @Caumons .. thats great complement...:)

Answer (score 2):

What about using a small flag to discard first call of ItemSelected ?

Comment: Where and how could I do this? I am out of ideas... :( I am already keeping track of a List with the positions shown... So, if the current position is not there and `onItemSelected()` is called then it is made by Android, else it is a user click but... It seems that Android recalls it when already displaying and this is hurting me! I think this is because of the recycling pattern done with Android (convertView)

Comment: I think that you should reset your counter every time a view is created or recycled (method getView of your adapter). Keep a counter for each view, reset it as the view is asked by the getView method. Discard first events of each view.

Comment: I think that this approach will get out my hands because I do not know exactly how is implemented the recycling and where I should reset the counter. I will try the other solution proposed by @sandy that seems much easier. I keep thinking that Google boys should improve this undesired behaviour of the method... Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: @Snicolas: How do I check the first call of ItemSelcted?

Comment: @lordzen With a boolean flag.